Bijection Homotopy classes of maps
Maybe it is a simple question but I would like to be sure about the principle behind it.
Let $[X,Y]$ denote the set of unbasepointed homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $Y$.
Suppose now $X$ is an $n$-dimensional connected manifold that is homotopy equivalent to a lower dimensional (say $k<n$) CW-complex $C$ of dimension $k$. Suppose $Y$ is an arbitrary (possibly infinite dimensional) connected CW-complex.
Can I conclude that there is an isomorphism between $[X,Y]$ and $[C,Y]$?
My reasoning is that I should be able to use the homotopy equivalence to decide the classes are the same. Are connectedness of $X$ and the fact I’m considering unbased-pointed classes important in this or can I relax them?

You don't need any assumptions on the spaces. In any category, any isomorphism $f:X' \to X$ induces an isomorphism of sets $\hom(X,Y) \to \hom(X',Y)$, $g \mapsto gf$. This is formal. Now apply it to the category $\mathbf{hTop}$, in which morphisms are homotopy classes of continuous maps, and isomorphisms are represented by homotopy equivalences (by definition) to get the statement for all spaces.

Thank you very much! :)
